# Find the next least number N that is N+1 = X^2 and (N/2)+1 = y^2?

Tags: linear-algebra, sums-of-squares

To go with this following task to create a proper equation ?

> Many numbers, especially from smaller ones, can rightly claim that
>   they are of particular interest to scientists. In the kingdom of the
>   right squares, the number 48 is particularly curious. If you add to it
>   1, you get a square [48 + 1 = 49 = 7x7], and if you split it half and
>   add 1 to the result, you will get another exact square [(48/2 = 24) +
>   1 = 25 = 5x5 ]. Both conditions are quite trivial, but together, they
>   are far less satisfied.
>
> In fact, 48 is the smallest number that satisfies both conditions. Can
>   you find the next least number that meets both conditions?

Comment: The numbers can easier be found by searching for positive integers $n$ such that both $n$ and $2n-1$ are perfect squares. This boils down to find the positive integers $k$ such that $2k^2-1$ is a perfect square. This leads to a variant of the Pell-equation : $$a^2-2b^2=-1$$

Comment: The first $4$ numbers satisfying the conditions are : $$48\ 1680\ 57120\ 1940448$$

Comment: @Peter why it is -1 not 0 ?

Comment: The square $m^2$ must be of the form $2k^2-1$, leading to $$m^2=2k^2-1$$ which is equivalent to $$m^2-2k^2=-1$$ or in other letters $$a^2-2b^2=-1$$

Comment: Also note that $(n/2+1)\cdot 2-1=n+1$